# ¿Cómo puedo convertir números en string a enteros?

Tags: c++

Tengo la variable de tipo *string* `numeros = "10,15,3"`.

¿Cómo puedo obtener los números de esa secuencia, separadas por las comas para hacelos operables?

Comment: Hola, porfavor date unos minutos en leer https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask para que puedas mejorar tu pregunta

Comment: puedes poner lo en un `std::stringstream` y lees un entero un caracter, y asi hasta que no quede nada.

Answer (score 0):

Escribo mi respuesta basado en lo que encontré en *StackOverflow en Inglés*, en en [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/236803/255257) a una pregunta similar

La función `split()` sirve para *separar* cadenas de caracteres en base a un delimitador, que en tu caso es la coma, pero puede ser cualquier otro caracter:

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

template <typename Out>
void split(const std::string &s, char delim, Out result) {
    std::istringstream iss(s);
    std::string item;
    while (std::getline(iss, item, delim)) {
        *result++ = item;
    }
}

std::vector<std::string> split(const std::string &s, char delim) {
    std::vector<std::string> elems;
    split(s, delim, std::back_inserter(elems));
    return elems;
}
```

La manera de llamar a la función es:

```
std::vector<std::string> x = split("10,15,3", ',');
```

Como puedes ver, al final `x` tendrá un vector con las cadenas `'10'`, `'15'` y `'3'`